# Get top 5 values from three tables with different prefix

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three tables namely a_sws, b_sws, c_sws.
They all have the same columns shown below.

```
salesman_id salesman_name  product_price product_quantity
```

I can get the top 5 highest sales on a single table by using this query:

```
SELECT salesman_id, salesman_name  , 
SUM(product_price * product_quantity) AS TotalSales
          FROM a_sws
          GROUP BY salesman_id
          ORDER BY SUM(product_price * product_quantity) DESC
          LIMIT 5;
```

How do I get the top 5 sales from the three tables?

Comment: Show the results that you want.  It is not clear how you want to combine the data, although `union all` comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume you want to sum a salesperson's records across the three tables, then `union all` comes to mind:

```
SELECT salesman_id, salesman_name,
       SUM(product_price * product_quantity) AS TotalSales
FROM ((SELECT salesman_id, salesman_name, product_price, product_quantity
       FROM a_sws
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT salesman_id, salesman_name, product_price, product_quantity
       FROM b_sws
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT salesman_id, salesman_name, product_price, product_quantity
       FROM c_sws
      )
     ) abc
GROUP BY salesman_id
ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Now for some commentary.  You should not be storing the salesperson id and name in the same table with the actual sales.  The id is sufficient; you should be looking up the name in the `SalesPerson` table.

Also, you should not have three tables with the same information.  This data should be going into a single table, probably with a column to identify the "type" or timeframe that was used to split the original data.